# Java sound class not looping

Tags: java, class, audio, javasound

I'm trying to develop a game and I've found 2 sources for sound.

I posted the whole class below, it won't seem to loop even when `looped_forever` or `loop_times` is setup to do so:

```
package com.jayitinc.ponygame;

import java.io.*;

import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class Sound
{
Thread t;
String read;
String name;

AudioInputStream stream = null;
AudioFormat format = null;

// New sound, the String it it's location relative to your project folder.
// I suggest you add a class folder in the project properties to access the
// files from there.
public Sound(String read, String name)
{
    sound = new File("sound/" + read);
    try
    {
        stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(sound);
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    format = stream.getFormat();
    this.name = name;
}

// New sound with set volume
public Sound(String read, float volume, String name)
{
    this(read, name);
    setVolume(volume);
    try
    {
        stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(sound);
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    format = stream.getFormat();
}

public void play()
{
    t = new Thread(play);
    // Write you own file location here and be aware that it need to be an
    // .wav file
    t.start();
}

// ONLY USE IF YOU HAVE STARTED THE THREAD FIRST
public void stop()
{
    // stops the sound thread from playing
    t.stop();
}

// Just in case you would like to change it
public void setVolume(float volume)
{
    this.volume = volume;
}

File sound;
boolean muted = false; // This should explain itself
float volume = 100.0f; // This is the volume that goes from 0 to 100
float pan = 0.0f; // The balance between the speakers 0 is both sides and it
                    // goes from -1 to 1
boolean isPlaying;

double seconds = 0.0d; // The amount of seconds to wait before the sound
                        // starts playing

boolean looped_forever = false; // It will keep looping forever if this is
                                // true

int loop_times = 0; // Set the amount of extra times you want the sound to
                    // loop (you don't need to have looped_forever set to
                    // true)
int loops_done = 0; // When the program is running this is counting the
                    // times the sound has looped so it knows when to stop

// The rest of this is pretty complicated, you don't need to bother with it.

final Runnable play = new Runnable() // This Thread/Runnable is for playing
                                        // the sound
{
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            // Check if the audio file is a .wav file
            if (sound.getName().toLowerCase().contains(".wav"))
            {

                if (format.getEncoding() != AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED)
                {
                    format = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, format.getSampleRate(), format.getSampleSizeInBits() * 2, format.getChannels(), format.getFrameSize() * 2, format.getFrameRate(), true);

                    stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(format, stream);
                }

                SourceDataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, stream.getFormat(), (int) (stream.getFrameLength() * format.getFrameSize()));

                SourceDataLine line = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
                line.open(stream.getFormat());
                line.start();

                // Set Volume
                FloatControl volume_control = (FloatControl) line.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
                volume_control.setValue((float) (Math.log(volume / 100.0f) / Math.log(10.0f) * 20.0f));

                // Mute
                BooleanControl mute_control = (BooleanControl) line.getControl(BooleanControl.Type.MUTE);
                mute_control.setValue(muted);

                FloatControl pan_control = (FloatControl) line.getControl(FloatControl.Type.PAN);
                pan_control.setValue(pan);

                int num_read = 0;
                byte[] buf = new byte[line.getBufferSize()];

                while ((num_read = stream.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) >= 0)
                {
                    int offset = 0;

                    while (offset < num_read)
                    {
                        offset += line.write(buf, offset, num_read - offset);
                    }
                }

                line.drain();
                line.stop();

                if (looped_forever)
                {
                    new Thread(play).start();
                } else if (loops_done < loop_times)
                {
                    loops_done++;
                    new Thread(play).start();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
public int getLength()
{
    long audioFileLength = sound.length();
    int frameSize = format.getFrameSize();
    float frameRate = format.getFrameRate();
    float durationInSeconds = (audioFileLength / (frameSize * frameRate));
    return (int) durationInSeconds;
}

public void setPan(float pan)
{
    this.pan = pan;
}

public float getPan()
{
    return pan;
}

public void setLoop(boolean loop)
{
    looped_forever = loop;
}

public boolean getLoop()
{
    return looped_forever;
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

**Edit:** I need to be able to control volume so if you have another class please make sure it can control volume!

Comment: Did you try using a debugger?

Comment: Why would you want to re-launch a new thread each time instead of just sending the data stream to the audio output multiple times?  This is much more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: Wow, almost 200 lines of broken code to loop a sound!  The [Java Sound tag Wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) shows code that successfully loops a sound in just 24 LOC.  Try that code.

Comment: I didn't code this, I actually did change that part of the code though to see if it worked. It was originally: if (looped_forever)
     {
      new Thread(play).start();
     } else if (loops_done < loop_times)
     {
      loops_done++;
      new Thread(play).start();
     }

Comment: @AndrewThompson I had something like that before but how do you control volume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (re `Clip`) ..how do you control volume?

Try this variant of the code seen on the [Java Sound tag Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info).

```
import java.net.URL;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class VolumeControl {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL(
            "http://pscode.org/media/leftright.wav");
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        // getAudioInputStream() also accepts a File or InputStream
        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.
            getAudioInputStream( url );
        clip.open(ais);
        Control[] c = clip.getControls();
        FloatControl temp = null;
        for (Control control : c) {
            System.out.println(control);
            if (control.toString().toLowerCase().contains("master gain")) {
                // we found it!
                temp = (FloatControl)control;
            }
        }
        final FloatControl vol = temp;
        clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JComponent c = null;
                if (vol!=null) {
                    final JSlider volControl = new JSlider(
                            (int)(100*vol.getMinimum()),
                            (int)(100*vol.getMaximum()),
                            (int)(100*vol.getValue())
                            );
                    ChangeListener cl = new ChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                            System.out.println( "Vol: " + volControl.getValue()/100f );
                            vol.setValue(volControl.getValue()/100f);
                        }
                    };
                    volControl.addChangeListener(cl);
                    c = volControl;
                } else {
                    c = new JLabel("Close to exit!");
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, c);
            }
        });
    }
}
```